Apache PLC4X S7 error: The number of requested items doesn't match the number of returned items
I am a bit new to PLC4X and programming in general. I want to read data from a snap7 Python simulator I have set up locally (source: https://python-snap7.readthedocs.io/en/1.3/API/server.html) with a service written in Java 17 (Spring Boot 2.5.0). My goal is to read about 1000 tags per second, or as fast as possible.
I am using PLC4X 0.12.0, and I have followed the instructions from the documentation and can read values normally up to a point. If I add more than 18 tagAddresses to the same connection, the application hangs, and I get the exception:
o.a.p.j.s.r.protocol.S7ProtocolLogic     : org.apache.plc4x.java.api.exceptions.PlcProtocolException: The number of requested items doesn't match the number of returned items
I can solve it by breaking down my list of tag addresses in batches, and then it works, but I was wondering if I was doing something wrong, or if this is intentional, maybe the simulator is at fault (I only changed some of the values I can read).
My code:
@Component
public class S7Poller {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(S7Poller.class);

    private PlcConnection connection;

    private static final LinkedHashMap<String, String> tagAddresses = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            connection = new DefaultPlcDriverManager()
               .getConnection("s7://localhost:1102?local-rack=0&local-slot=1");
        } catch (PlcConnectionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("Error connecting to the PLC: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cron}")
    public void readPLC() {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                PlcReadRequest.Builder readRequest = connection.readRequestBuilder();

                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean1", "%DB1.DBX0:0:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean2", "%DB1.DBX0:1:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean3", "%DB1.DBX0:2:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean4", "%DB1.DBX0:3:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean5", "%DB1.DBX0:4:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean6", "%DB1.DBX0:5:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean7", "%DB1.DBX0:6:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("boolean8", "%DB1.DBX0:7:BOOL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("sint1", "%DB1.DBB10:SINT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("sint2", "%DB1.DBB11:SINT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("sint3", "%DB1.DBB12:SINT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("sint4", "%DB1.DBB13:SINT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("usint1", "%DB1.DBB20:USINT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("usint2", "%DB1.DBB21:USINT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("int1", "%DB1.DBW30:INT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("int2", "%DB1.DBW32:INT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("int3", "%DB1.DBW34:INT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("int4", "%DB1.DBW36:INT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("int5", "%DB1.DBW38:INT");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("real1", "%DB1.DBD60:REAL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("real2", "%DB1.DBD76:REAL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("real3", "%DB1.DBD92:REAL");
                readRequest.addTagAddress("string1", "%DB1.DBX100:STRING");


                PlcReadRequest rr = readRequest.build();
                PlcReadResponse response = rr.execute().get();

                logResponses(response);

            } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }

    private void logResponses(PlcReadResponse response) {
        LOG.info("boolean1: " + response.getBoolean("boolean1"));
        LOG.info("boolean2: " + response.getBoolean("boolean2"));
        LOG.info("boolean3: " + response.getBoolean("boolean3"));
        LOG.info("boolean4: " + response.getBoolean("boolean4"));
        LOG.info("boolean5: " + response.getBoolean("boolean5"));
        LOG.info("boolean6: " + response.getBoolean("boolean6"));
        LOG.info("boolean7: " + response.getBoolean("boolean7"));
        LOG.info("boolean8: " + response.getBoolean("boolean8"));
        LOG.info("sint1: " + response.getInteger("sint1"));
        LOG.info("sint2: " + response.getInteger("sint2"));
        LOG.info("sint3: " + response.getInteger("sint3"));
        LOG.info("sint4: " + response.getInteger("sint4"));
        LOG.info("usint1: " + response.getInteger("usint1"));
        LOG.info("usint2: " + response.getInteger("usint2"));
        LOG.info("int1: " + response.getInteger("int1"));
        LOG.info("int2: " + response.getInteger("int2"));
        LOG.info("int3: " + response.getInteger("int3"));
        LOG.info("int4: " + response.getInteger("int4"));
        LOG.info("int5: " + response.getInteger("int5"));
        LOG.info("real1: " + response.getFloat("real1"));
        LOG.info("real2: " + response.getFloat("real2"));
        LOG.info("real3: " + response.getFloat("real3"));
        LOG.info("string1: " + response.getString("string1"));
    }



Generally this should quirk without manually batching things, as the driver should be doing this for you. We even have test cases that extensively test this on various types of s7 devices. I would assume that possibly the simulator you are using has issues.if you create an issue in github and could create a Wireshark recording and attach that to the issue, I could have a look this Friday.

@ChristoferDutz Hello, yes I think the simulator might be the problem, but I cannot verify it. Have not found many open source S7 simulators out there to test. Thank you for your time, I posted it on Github with Wireshark.

That's a huge problem in that space ... Siemens being particularly restrictive with giving out stuff.
There is ModbusPal available for ModbusTCP, Eclipse Milo for an OPC-UA server or you could even use Beckhoff TwinCat to start a simulated PLC for free ... but for Siemens, unfortunately no Luck.
